# count multiple distinct fields by group with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a data set looks as

```
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":100,"UserName":"tom"}
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":200,"UserName":"tom"}
{"BrandId":"b","SessionId":300,"UserName":"mike"}
```

I would like to count distinct session and username group by brandid, the sample sql is like:

```
select brandid,count_distinct(sessionid),count_distinct(username)
from data
group by brandid
```

I tried to write Mongo DB, my current code is as following and it does not work. Is there anyway to make it work?

```
db.logs.aggregate([ 
    {$group:{
        _id:{brand:"$BrandId",user:"$UserName",session:"$SessionId"},  
        count:{$sum:1}}}, 
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id.brand",
        users:{$sum:"$_id.user"},
        sessions:{$sum:"$_id.session"}
    }}
])
```

for the certain example, the expected count is

```
{"BrandId:"a","countSession":2,"countUser":1}
{"BrandId:"b","countSession":1,"countUser":1}
```

if you know SQL, the expect result is as same as the SQL I mentioned.

Comment: @JohnnyHK no. Definely it is not the problem. If you know anything about how to count multiple fields, please let me know.

Comment: What's the expected/desired output?

Comment: @chridam I add expected output to question. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) to accumulate the distinct set of `SessionId` and `UserName` values during the `$group`, and then adding a [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage to your pipeline that uses the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator to get the size of each set:

```javascript
db.logs.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: '$BrandId', 
        sessionIds: {$addToSet: '$SessionId'}, 
        userNames: {$addToSet: '$UserName'}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0, 
        BrandId: '$_id', 
        countSession: {$size: '$sessionIds'}, 
        countUser: {$size: '$userNames'}
    }}
])
```

Result:

```javascript
{
    "BrandId" : "b",
    "countSession" : 1,
    "countUser" : 1
}, 
{
    "BrandId" : "a",
    "countSession" : 2,
    "countUser" : 1
}
```